# How do I correctly set up a Marionette EventAggregator as a Require.js module

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I'm trying to setup a vent/EventAggregator as a separate Require.js module. I am using Marionette 1.0.2 (which I believe has a different implementation than legacy versions pre 1.0.0) with wreqr included: this code is from backbone.marionette.js:-

```
        // Event Aggregator
// ----------------
// A pub-sub object that can be used to decouple various parts
// of an application through event-driven architecture.

Wreqr.EventAggregator = (function(Backbone, _){
  "use strict";
  var EA = function(){};

  // Copy the `extend` function used by Backbone's classes
  EA.extend = Backbone.Model.extend;

  // Copy the basic Backbone.Events on to the event aggregator
  _.extend(EA.prototype, Backbone.Events);

  return EA;
})(Backbone, _);
```

When I set up my vent.js module what should it be? Something like this:-

```
define(['marionette'],function(Marionette){
    return new Marionette.EventAggregator();
})
```

Also in my require config should I explicitly be including backbone.wreqr.js or not? Or should just the marionette file (see snippet from above) be sufficient?

For reference here is my app.js:-

```
require.config({

    paths : {
        backbone : 'lib/backbone',
        underscore : 'lib/underscore',
        jquery : 'lib/jquery',
        marionette : 'lib/backbone.marionette',
        'backbone.wreqr' : 'lib/backbone.wreqr',
        text : 'lib/text',
        templates : '../templates'

    },
    shim : {
        jquery : {
            exports : 'jQuery'
        },
        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },
        backbone : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
            exports : 'Marionette'
        },
        'backbone.wreqr' : {
            deps : ['backbone', 'marionette', 'underscore'],
            exports : 'Wreqr'
        }
    }
})

require(
    ["jquery",
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "marionette",
        "backbone.wreqr",
        "shell/shellapp"
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Wreqr, ShellApp) {
        $(function() {
           //new ShellApp();
            var shell = ShellApp;
            shell.start();
            trace("shell: "+shell);
        });
    }
);
```

All help much appreciated!

Much thanks,

Sam

__*_*____****** UPDATE

Thanks to Paul I figured out how to get my vent.js working. FYI I did NOT need to import the wreqr file seperately in the config. Here is the vent.js code:-

```
define(['backbone', 'marionette'],function(Backbone, Marionette){
    return new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs - think the marionette file should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Paul Grime. Sadly though when I follow the tutorial, only importing Marionette (with Wreqr.EventAggregator in it) and use this for the vent module - `define(['marionette'],function(Marionette){
    return new Marionette.EventAggregator();
})`  I get the following error on the return line - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Any ideas what might be happening? Much thanks, Sam.

Comment: `console.log(Marionette, Marionette["EventAggregator"])` in that module to see which is undefined first. Then check that `EventAggregator` is actually included in the marionette JS file. In fact, this source line - https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L2046 shows that `EventAggregator` is accessed as `Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. When I search through the Marionette object in the console, Wreqr is not there. As you say, it is in the Backbone object BUT I can't access the Wreqr object when I try to log it on the console. I can see it in the object explorer BUT I get undefined when I try to use console.log(Backbone.Wreqr); or console.log(Backbone["Wreqr"]); my vent.js looks like this now:- define(['backbone'],function(Backbone){
    console.log(Backbone.Wreqr);
})    Any ideas why I can't acces the Wreqr object? Thanks again, Sam

Comment: Does *your* marionette.js file have the same code as the link posted above? It may not be the same version/file. Even if it does, it could be that the separate loading of the Wreqr file breaks this. If your version of marionette *does* have the Wreqr field then remove `backbone.wreqr` shim, otherwise they could conflict.

Comment: It is version 1.0.2 as well and appears to be the same file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/MjBKH/4/).

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: 'http://backbonejs.org/backbone',
        underscore: 'http://underscorejs.org/underscore',
        jquery: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1',
        marionette: 'http://marionettejs.com/downloads/backbone.marionette'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        }
    }
});

require(["backbone", "marionette"], function (Backbone, Marionette) {
    console.log(Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator);
    var ea = new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();
    console.log(ea);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I really appreciate your time and effort. It's a huge help for me as a stumble around my first Marionette app!

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but am trying to use the core amd build of marionette and include the wreqr file separately. I am getting Backbone is not defined error when trying to create a new instance of application.